# Is there a way I can give 20% width to a div and the remainder of width to another div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have the following simple HTML:

```
<article id="root-view">
   <div id="menu-view">
      x
   </div>
   <div id="content-view">
      y
   </div>
</div>
```

I set the style of menu-view to width: 20% and content-view to width: 80%

I would like to now give the menu-view: width: 40rem and have the remainder allocated to the content-view.

Is there a way that I can do this with CSS? I've not seen a setting that I could use for content-view's width? Note that we are using browsers IE9 and above.

Comment: give root-view specific width. and menu-view: 40rem. content-view will get the rest.

Comment: Okay so you're saying I don't need to use calc() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**`calc()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set `#content-view`'s width to `100%` subtracted by `40rem`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/bC5QV/1/) - Full screen [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/bC5QV/1/embedded/result/) might work better.

```
#content-view {
    width:calc(100% - 40rem);
}
```

This is equivalent to the remaining space.

---

Alternatively, you could use CSS tables:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/9HGN3/) - Full screen [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/9HGN3/embedded/result/)

```
#root-view {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
#menu-view {
    display:table-cell;
    width:40rem;
}
#content-view {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: With your fiddle I just see a red area and another area below. It doesn't seem to show any widths.

Comment: @SamanthaJ This is because the result window is less than `40rem`. Look at this example using `4rem` instead.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/bC5QV/2/

Comment: Thanks Josh. I will try this out. My office mate suggested I use CSS Tables. Do you think that's also a good alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#content-view { 
float:right;
margin-left:20%;
width:80%; }

#menu-view{
float:left;
margin-right:80%;
width:20%; }
```